# XLS => nested JSON

Tags: json, node.js, excel, spreadsheet, xlsx

I'm using the handing xlsx-to-json npm package, and it's quite fine. There is an option to target an individual sheet, but no quick way to nest objects. I know this is because the nature of spreadsheets is A:1, limited to 1 data level.

I've established that we could have multiple sheets and stitch them into a 2 level deep object `{a:{1:x},b:{2:z}}` --- but anything deep than that, in this approach, would require an additional sheet. This would get out of hand, fast.

Likely there is no way around limitation and I am barking up the wrong tree, however, it's worth asking the brilliant folks here if there is a method to use XSL to output nested objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is very tedious and probably not worth it, it is theoretically possible to simulate any relational database in xls. And relational databases can be transformed to deeply nested objects.

So yes, it is certainly possible, but it's probably a road you don't want to go down.

As an example: you could have 1 sheet with customers, 1 sheet with orders, and 1 sheet with order lines. Using id's to uniquely reference certain customers, orders and order lines, you can have them refer to eachother and create different kinds of nested json objects. For example, Customers with multiple orders, with multiple order lines. Or orders with a customer and multiple order lines.

Comment: I suspect the best approach for this would be to swap the XLS for a streamlined MongoDB interface. To avoid flat or relational conversion into nesting, start with nested dictionaries. Thank you for being a voice of good reason.